# How can I remove the "magnifying glass" icon in my searchBar?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to hide using "search.showsScopeBar = false" but it don't work.

```
 public var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
            let search = UISearchBar()
            search.showsScopeBar = false
             search.barTintColor = .backgroundColor
            search.text = "Selecione ou digite "
            return search
        }()
```

I want to hide this icon [Lupa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyqge.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scopebar isn't what you think it is.  It's a customised segmented control that can be used with the searchbar, not the magnifiying glass you are tyring to remove.

You should use the `func setImage(_ iconImage: UIImage?, for icon: UISearchBar.Icon, state: UIControl.State)` API.  You can also use this to change any of the other icons in the search bar.

To remove the icon set the image to an empty image:

```
      let searchBar: UISearchBar = {
         let sb = UISearchBar()
         sb.placeholder = "Search here"
         let emptyImage = UIImage()
         sb.setImage(emptyImage, for: .search, state: .normal)
         return sb
      }()
```

Or you can change the image to whatever image you like.  The following will put the pencil in a circle image:

```
sb.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "pencil.circle"), for: .search, state: .normal)
```